# Splitting hairs whilst splitting strings

Tags: string, pattern-matching, idris

I tried to make a function in Idris like so:

```
strSplit : String -> Maybe (Char, String)
```

This would 'un-cons' the string into its first `Char` and the rest of the string, and return `Nothing` if it were empty.

So I wrote this, which failed:

```
strSplit x = case strM of
    StrNil       => Nothing
    StrCons c cd => Just (c, cs)
```

So I then tried this, a bit like in `Prelude.Strings`:

```
strSplit x with (strM x)
    strSplit ""             | StrNil         = Nothing
    strSplit (strCons c cs) | (StrCons c cs) = Just (c, cs)
```

Which compiled and ran with no problems.

My question is, why do I have to use that `with` rule to split a string in this way, and why does my original method fail?

*Note: Sorry, I can't access an interpreter at the moment, so I can't write the error message here yet.*

Comment: I don't know Idris, but you've got yourself one of the best-titled questions on stackoverflow, my friend :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here. Firstly, in the 'case' block, the argument is `strM` rather than `strM x` as it is in the 'with' block, so you're inspecting different things.

There's a more interesting problem though, which is that if you try fixing the first one:

```
strSplit : String -> Maybe (Char, String)
strSplit x = case strM x of
    StrNil       => Nothing
    StrCons c cd => Just (c, cs)
```

You'll get a different error (this is from current master which has reworded error messages):

```
Type mismatch between
    StrM "" (Type of StrNil)
and
    StrM x (Expected type)
```

So the distinction between 'case' and 'with' is that 'with' takes into account that the thing you're inspecting may influence the types and values on the left hand side. In the 'case', matching strM x means that x *must* be "", but a 'case' can appear anywhere and takes no account of the effect on the types of the other arguments (working out appropriate type checking rules for this would be quite a challenge...).

On the other hand, 'with' can only appear at the top level: effectively what it's doing is adding another top level thing to match on which, being top level, *can* affect the types and values of the other patterns.

So, the short answer is that 'with' supports dependent pattern matching, but 'case' does not.

Comment: Whoops, the code above was what I meant, but I made a typo. Thanks for correcting me!